# Unable to send mail from Yahoo mail account using any browser

Tags: yahoo-mail

The incoming mails are received as usual but I’m unable to send mail from Yahoo mail account.

While trying to send any mail from my Yahoo account, I am getting the blank screen. Only thing is the browser address bar shows this address:

```
http://in-mg61.mail.yahoo.com/neo/b/compose?&.rand=381039365
```

What could be the possible reason and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this advice of yahoo: http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_ML&id=SLN3569&impressions=false

> Cannot reply to, forward, or send emails
>
> Resolution
>
> The inability to send, reply, or forward emails can be
>   caused by a program on your computer that prevents the Yahoo! Mail
>   Rich Text toolbar from launching properly. As a workaround, try
>   switching to plain text mode when you send an email.
>
> To switch to
>   plain text mode:
>
> Sign in to Yahoo! Mail. Click the Compose button to
>   start a new email. Click the double arrow button (<<) at the right
>   side of the formatting toolbar (just below the email's subject line).
>   This switches you to plain text mode. Compose and send your email.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue with the yahoo mail in chrome.

After a little trial and error I find this is the format works:

```
http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?To={to}&Cc={cc}&Bcc={bcc}&Subj={subject}&Body={body}
```

I added a custom URL using the chrome "Mailto: 1.26.0"  extension.   Works great now!  When I click on an email link it opens a yahoo mail and the to field is populated correctly.

Hope this helps other people who were struggling with this.

Answer (score -2):

It may be the internet browser, you are using. I had this problem until I downloaded Google Chrome, once I downloaded Google Chrome I was back in business.

Comment: Please don't use excess punctuation.  Someone else has to take the time to clean it up.